# Microsoft.CluRecognizer not registered in factory

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, language-studio

In bot framework composer implementing CLU.Recognizer, following https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/ConversationLanguageUnderstanding/dotnet

when working on local environment it is working but on azure vm receiving exception Microsoft.CluRecognizer not registered in factory.

checked variables in vm and everything is same. following is from main dialog file

```
"$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/stable/Composer/packages/server/schemas/sdk.schema",
"generator": "*****.lg",
"id": "*****_chatbot",
"recognizer": {
  "$kind": "Microsoft.CluRecognizer",
  "projectName": "${settings.languageStudio.clu.projectName}",
  "endpoint": "${settings.languageStudio.endpoint}",
  "endpointKey": "${settings.languageStudio.endpointKey}",
  "deploymentName": "${settings.languageStudio.clu.deploymentName}"
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What version of the CLU package are you using? What version of the SDK? Is it a dotnet or JS bot?